# How to show subtotal and total of groups in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am making an SSRS report in following format:

```
DIVISION  
      SECTOR  
            DEPARTMENT
```

Division contain Sector and Sector contain Department so resulting report becomes something like following. A figure is being shown against each Department and I want to show SUBTOTAL of each Sector right against Sector column (by adding all Department coming under it) and then show TOTAL of Division (by adding all Department or all Sector) at the end. How do I show these totals?

```
Division1
     Sector1               SUBTOTAL HERE (for e.g. 19,000)
          Department1      10,000
          Department2      9,000
     Sector2               SUBTOTAL HERE  (for e.g. 8,000)
          Department3      8,000
     Sector3               SUBTOTAL HERE  (for e.g. 13,000)
          Department4      10,000
          Department5      1,000
          Department6      2,000
                           TOTAL HERE  (for e.g. 40,000)
Division2
     Sector4               SUBTOTAL HERE (for e.g. 3,500)
          Department7      3,500
                           TOTAL HERE (for e.g. 3,500)
```

My report is displaying all divisions, sectors and departments with figures like above (I am using groups ) but how do I display SUBTOTAL and TOTAL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for this report I will assume you have three groups in your `Row Groups Pane` (Row groups will be there either you use a Matrix or Tablix).

```
DIVISION    (DIVISION Group) 

       SECTOR       (SECTION Group)    

              DEPARTMENT    (Details Group)
```

Adding totals and sub totals are probably the simplest task in SSRS. See below goto your Row groups pane and add Totals to all the groups you want to, Which will appear as Totals and Sub Totals in your report.

[image]

Comment: Ok I did that and it just adds a blank row. Do I also need to write an expression in column where I want to display total?